# Spring Security - OAuth2 and CustomAuthenticationProvider. How to configure different URL pattern for each one?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My project has two authentication providers: Google OAuth2 client (oauth2 starter dependency) and a second custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

And I have two `antMatcher`: `/api/**` and `/app/**`.

Is it possible to authorize the `/app/**` with OAuth2 and `/api/**` with my custom authentication provider?

Because I don't want OAuth2 enabled for the REST API, but want OAuth SSO for the rest of the application.

How can I specify different URL pattern for different Authentication Provider?

**Edit**

Follow my configuration (Spring Boot 2.0.2):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .permitAll()
    }
}
```

Tried different configurations but none worked

Comment: Could you add OAuth2 and custom authentication configuration ? Also show how filter, authentication manage and provider is registered. May be something is not set up correctly. What is your spring security oauth and spring boot version ?

Comment: @user2683814 I've edit my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

The AuthenticationProvider has a method: supports(Class authentication) 
which accepts the authentication token, if it returns false the AuthenticationManager will not call that Provider.

Hence you could put a custom field into the Authentication Token to indicate which URI is being called, the Authentication interface has a getDetails() method that returns an Object, were you can provide the additional information.

To do this you need to create a custom AuthenticationDetails and AuthenticationDetailsSource, you could extend WebAuthenticationDetails and WebAuthenticationDetailsSource. 
The WebAuthenticationDetailsSource has a buildDetails method that gives you access to the HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Thank you. I can do it on my custom Authentication Provider, but how can I disable some URL pattern for OAuth?

Comment: Have you considered setting up 2 separate filter chains? this is how I have done these type of things in the past. If you create 2 security classes that implement the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter spring will configure 2 filter chains. One filter chain can be for /api and the there /app. It keeps things nice and seperate, you can use the @Order annotation to determine which one should get evaluated first. Spring will try each filter chain against the uri untill there is a match and then will not match any others. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/08/spring-security-multiple-filter-chains.html

Comment: I tried two separate filter chains, but it seems the oauth filter is applying globally. In out of ideas to limit oauth2 provider to a subset of antMatcher e let others antMatcher for a custom jwt authentication provider

Answer (score 0):

As you have two Authentication Providers, you need to configure two Authentication Managers. Here's a sample XML configuration for your reference:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="appAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="appAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:authentication-manager id="apiAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="apiAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Then configure security protection rules for endpoints.

```
<sec:filter-security-metadata-source id="appServerSecurityMetadataSource"
                                     request-matcher="ant"
                                     use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/check_token" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('PRIVATE_SERVICE')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('PRIVATE_SERVICE')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/jwt-token" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('PRIVATE_SERVICE')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll()"/>

    <sec:expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:filter-security-metadata-source>


<sec:filter-security-metadata-source id="apiServerSecurityMetadataSource"
                                     request-matcher="ant"
                                     use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('ACTIVE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll()"/>

    <sec:expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
```

Then configure filter security interceptor: (Configure similar interceptor for `apiAuthenticationManager` as well)

```
<bean id="appSecurityInterceptorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="appAuthenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="appServerSecurityMetadataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Last step is to register these filter beans:

```
<bean id="appServerSecurityFilterRegistration" class="org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean">
    <property name="filter" ref="appSecurityInterceptorFilter"/>
    <property name="enabled" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

**Edit:** To bypass some requests from entire filter chain:

Create an path matcher for all `/api/**` requests.

```
<bean id="apiRequestMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/api/**"/>
</bean>
```

Create an empty filter chain to bypass all filters for `/api/**` requests.

```
<bean id="apiFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain">
    <constructor-arg name="requestMatcher" ref="apiRequestMatcher"/>
    <constructor-arg name="filters">
        <list/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Finally, register this to filter chain proxy.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="apiFilterChain"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

For delegating these requests to your custom provider follow the steps I shared earlier.

You can also try, `<http pattern="/api/**" security="none"/>` to bypass filter chain. Spring 3.1 replaced `filters=”none”` with a `security=”none”`.

Comment: does not work. oauth2 provider still process the `/api/**` matcher. Is there any way to oauth2 provider completely ignore `/api/**` matcher and spring-security delegate this matcher to the CustomProvider?

Comment: but now all requests to `/api/**` are unsecured

Comment: Yes, that is what it'd do. Steps I shared before edit should do the intended work. Now, I guess it'd be difficult for people to assist you without checking your authentication configuration.

Comment: Its not possible to figure out the problem just with web security configuration. Kindly play around with the configuration and share a specific issue.